# Return all elements from list that don't have a record. (MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of feeds:

```
('feed1', 'feed2', 'feed3')
```

I also have a table `feeds` with a list of feeds, I need to find which feeds in my search list don't appear in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE `feeds_filtered` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ......
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

For example feed1 and feed3 exist in my table so I want feed 2 returned.
***Please note:*** that the feeds table also has feed4, feed5 etc so I don't want them returned either. Only feed2

I can easily write a PHP script to do this, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this is MySQL?

Thanks in adavnce!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a temporary table, do a `LEFT JOIN`, then get the records where the RHS of the join is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the items from one table that don't appear on another table, ie:

```
select * from feeds_filtered where url not in (select url from feeds)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a query like:

```
select * from feeds_filtered
where url is not in ('feed1', 'feed3')
```

Comment: Except that the asker wants to do it the other way around.